# How to update the meta information from dynamic data using vue-meta in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-meta

I have articles that have their respective meta descriptions. I am using `vue-meta` to replace the default meta descriptions. I tried using async and mounted property to fetch the information from my API but I don't see any changes in the head i.e. in the meta descriptions of the respective articles. I still see the default set by Vue js.

This is what I have:

```
<script lang="ts">

import { Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import VueMeta from 'vue-meta';

Vue.use(VueMeta);

export default class ArticleContent extends Vue {
  article: any | null = null;
  articlelist: any = null;
  id = 1;

  async mounted(): Promise<any> {
    this.article = this.articlelist.find((f: any) => {     <-- slug
      return f.title_slug === this.$route.params.id;
    });
    this.articlelist = await this.asyncData();
  }

  async asyncData(): Promise<any> {
    const articlelist = await this.$axios.get(             <-- call to my api
      'https://my_api...'
    );
    return articlelist.data.data;
  }

    metaInfo(): any {                                      <-- meta information
    return {
      title: 'Article',
      meta: [
        {
          hid: this.articlelist[0]._id,
          name: this.articlelist[0].productNames['en'],
          content: this.articlelist[0].metaDescription['en'],
        },
      ],
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

I would appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: Are you using Nuxt? Also, can you see whether the data is being fetched in your browser's network tab?

Comment: @DelenaMalan yes I am using Nuxt and the call to my API does return something.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rather then using `asyncData` you can use `serverPrefetch`

try this

```
 serverPrefetch():Promise<any> {
  // this function should return Promise
   return this.$axios.get(
      'https://my_api...'
    ).then(result => {
          this.articlelist = result.data.data
      });

  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Could you please expand your answer a bit? I am a bit confused about what being returned in that method and how I could use it.

Comment: Hi @AlyssaAlex  I have updated the code, actually  `serverPrefetch` should return a Promise.

Comment: Hi, I don't get any response from my API unfortunately with this method on inspection from my network tab. Should I be keeping `this.articlelist = this.serverPrefetch(); ` in the mounted method?